# Grails 3.1.9 missing command (create-functional-test)

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, functional-testing, geb, grails-3.1

I want migrate Geb functional tests from 1.3.7 to 3.1.9. Tried to create a new plain test with `grails create-functional-test` in IntelliJ an via console. Both failed with `Command not found create-functional-test`.

I created a new application with `grails create-app` and tried again `grails create-functional-test`, it works as expected.

Compared and improved all Grails dependencies in `build.gradle`.

Any ideas how i can fix this issue?

**EDIT:**

If i uncomment this line: `//compile "org.grails.plugins:geb:0.13.1"` in `build.gradle` File it is possible to create a Testfile but of course Grails does not know  the `GebSpec` class.

**EDIT 2:** I solved it!

The old Plugin, see above, caused the problem. I deleted the dependency and reimported my apllication, know it works.